# ¿Como puedo crear un popup o ventana emergente en una app java?

Tags: java, java-swing, jframe, popup

Buenas tardes.

Estoy haciendo una app de escritorio usando la librería de java swing y me encuentro atascado con un problema de popups.

En mi app, hay unos checkbox que al marcarlos te tiene que aparecer un popup con varias opciones a elegir, spinners, textfields, labels, etc....

Las opciones que he encontrado no me convencen, un jdialog se me hace muy limitado para mis necesidades (o no se como personalizarlo al max.). También he probado con internal frame, pero no consigo que al aparecer, aparezca con el tamaño necesario (he probado el .pack y todas las opciones que he encontrado en internet), además que lo que necesito es un recuadrito que aparezca con lo que necesito (Como un tooltip pero con más elementos no solo texto)

Mi última opción y que me parecia funcionar perfectamente, era hacer otro JFrame con la posición en pantalla calculada por una función que cree, parecía ser la solución perfecta, pero al abrir la app en una ventana principal y moverlo a otra, los frame se siguen abriendo en la ventana anterior....

Sabéis alguna manera que pueda realizar esto más sencilla o al menos alguna forma de que el JFrame aparezca en la misma pantalla en la que se encuentra la app

Gracias y un saludo.

Comment: A unJDialog le puedes dar el mismo estilo que a unJFrame ya que todo  lo puedes meter dentro de un panel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes crear un `JOptionPane` que permita mostrar los componentes que tu desees, creas un `JPanel` y añades los componente que vayas a utilizar:

```
 JPanel panel = new JPanel();
 panel.add(new JLabel("A:"));
 panel.add(new JTextField(12));
 panel.add(new JLabel("B:"));
 panel.add(new JTextField(12));
 JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(forms, panel);
```

Apartir de aqui ya puedes jugar con las opciones que selecciones en el JOption, puedes ponerle listener a los componentes que ubiques dentro del panel o cuando le des click a las opciones de la ventana emergente tomar decisiones.

lo que dices del `checkbox` ya queda a criterio tuyo como quieres lanzar la ventana emergente.

Comment: Muchisimas gracías. No encontraba la forma de personalizar un JDialog.

Unas últimas preguntas:

1.- El JDialog siempre aparece al centro de la ventana, ¿Hay alguna forma de cambiar su posición en pantalla?

2.- Puedo hacer que el JDialog salga con un JFrame sin titulo en la parte de arriba y opciones de cierre, etc...

Seguramente sean preguntas que me pueda responder probando pero estoy fuera de casa y no puedo ponerlo en practica. Muchas gracias por la respuesta